# jQuery isn't working in my HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the HTML document where I want to call it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='menuTest.js'></script>
    <title>Menu Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="hover" style="height:80px; width:150px; background-color:black; margin-left:100px; margin-top:100px"></div>
    <p id="show">this will appear</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the jQuery script that I am trying to link, was originally trying to get something to appear on hover, then tried to place a html object to see if it was even linked properly (it wasn't):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseover(function(){
        $('p').show();
    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $('p').hide();
    $('div').after("<p>Hooo</p>");
    });
});
```

I know its something stupid I'm missing but I've looked at other jQuery examples and still haven't figured it out.

Thanks!

Comment: You should include jQuery

Answer (score 5):

Just add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

before `</head>` and any other scripts that require jQuery. For example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='menuTest.js'></script>
    <title>Menu Test</title>
</head>
```

---

`menuTest.js` also contains errors. Fixed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseover(function(){
        $('p').show();
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $('p').hide();
    });
    $('div').after("<p>Hooo</p>");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H5hg6/1/

Comment: Preferably before including the other script, as it's expecting `$` to exist.

Answer (score 4):

Another one mistake, You forgot to complete a `parenthesis` and a `curly brace`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div').mouseover(function(){
        $('p').show(); 
    });     //------------------------------------> here.

    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $('p').hide();
        $('div').after("<p>Hooo</p>");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Murali Sent the details to you and I was scheduled for a telephonic interview last week for round 2, Forgot to include this.. And i'll delete this comment soon..

Answer (score -1):

You should include jquery

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='menuTest.js'></script>
    <title>Menu Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="hover" style="height:80px; width:150px; background-color:black; margin-left:100px; margin-top:100px"></div>
    <p id="show">this will appear</p>
</body>
</html>
```